# How to wrap a C++11 callback?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, casablanca

I'm using [Casablanca C++ Rest SDK](https://casablanca.codeplex.com/) for http connections. Here is a basic piece of code that makes a http request.

Copied from [Casablanca documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj950081.aspx):

```
// Creates an HTTP request and prints the length of the response stream.
pplx::task<void> HTTPStreamingAsync()
{
    http_client client(L"http://www.google.com");

    // Make the request and asynchronously process the response. 
    return client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
    {
        // Response received, do whatever here.
    });
}
```

This will do an asynchronous request and do a callback when done. I need to make my own class that uses these codes and I want to wrap it to my own callback.

For simplicity, assume that I want to make a class that has method which print html code of google.com.

So I expected something like this:

```
MyClass myObject;
myObject.getGoogleHTML([](std::string htmlString)
{
    std::cout << htmlString;
});
```

I searched and read related articles like:

1. [C++ class member callback simple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189440/c-class-member-callback-simple-examples)
2. [C++11 styled callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338695/c11-styled-callbacks)
3. [Friday Q&A 2011-06-03: Objective-C Blocks vs. C++0x Lambdas: Fight!](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-06-03-objective-c-blocks-vs-c0x-lambdas-fight.html)

But I'm still a bit confused as I get used with `completion block` in `Objective-C`. How can I construct such a class that wraps callback?

Comment: You mean something like a `T` representing the lambda and just forwarding it to `then`?

Comment: @chris: yes, please suggest.

Comment: Sorry if it's just me being new-ish to web stuff, but where does the string in your callsite lambda come from?

Comment: @chris: please look at the lambda above, you see that there is a http_response. All I expected is to have this http_response passed to my class's lambda. std::string is a just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the lambda as a general type. As a bonus, it'll work with any other callable object.

```
template<typename F>
pplx::task<void> MyClass::getGoogleHTML(F f) {
    http_client client(L"http://www.google.com");
    return client.request(methods::GET).then(f);
}
```

You could also perfectly forward `f` via `F &&f` and `.then(std::forward<F>(f))` if you wish. If you're actually looking to extract something to give to the passed-in lambda, pass a lambda to `then` that captures `f` and calls it with that extracted data.