# Can i create in-class function types?

Tags: c++, function

I am working on a little project containing simple server which listens to messages.

Assuming we have the following classes:

```
class Message;

class Server
{
    void handler1(Message msg);
    void handler2(Message msg);
    .
    .
    .
    void handler19(Message msg);
};
```

Can i create a new function type of the class `Server` that returns `void` and gets a single `Message` variable called msg like this:

```
typedef void(Server::*MessageHandler)(Message msg);
```

So the class declaration would be:

```
class Server
{
    MessageHandler handler1;
    .
    .
    .
    MessageHandler handler19;
}
```

A thing as mentioned would come handy with sqlite3 callback functions (where the function declaration is not the cleanest).

If it is possible, how can i implement such function?

If this is not possible, is there any similar way of making the code more simple (like C# delegates)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think this is a particular good idea.

Comment: If you have access to C++11, you could try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338695/c11-styled-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

For the code:

```
class Server {
    void handler1(Message msg); // This declares a method named handler one which takes a Message and returns void
    void(Server::*handler)(Message); // This declares a member variable named handler of the type Server method pointer to a method that takes a Message and returns a void
};
```

`handler` can be reassigned with any `Server` method which takes a `Message` and returns `void`. But it must be initialized before it is first used; something like: `handler = handler1` at this point a call to `handler` would be a call to `handler1`. But `handler` could then be reassigned at will, for example if you did: `handler = handler2` at this point a call to `handler` would be a call to `handler2`.

I wasn't sure from your question if you understood, but `handler` never defines a method; only a pointer to one.

Given this definition of `Server`:

```
class Server {
    void Handler1(int param) { cout << param + 1 << endl; }
    void Handler2(int param) { cout << (param << 1) << endl; }
    void Handler3(int param) { cout << (param != 0 ? "true\n" : "false\n"); }
    void Handler4(int param) { cout << static_cast<char>(param + 'A') << endl; }
public:
    function<void(Server, int)> handler_;
    void next() {
        if (!handler_ || *handler_.target<void (Server::*)(int)>() == &Server::Handler4) {
            handler_ = &Server::Handler1;
        } else if(*handler_.target<void (Server::*)(int)>() == &Server::Handler1) {
            handler_ = &Server::Handler2;
        } else if (*handler_.target<void (Server::*)(int)>() == &Server::Handler2) {
            handler_ = &Server::Handler3;
        } else {
            handler_ = &Server::Handler4;
        }
    }
};
```

You could do the following:

```
Server foo;

for (auto i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; ++i) {
    foo.next();
    foo.handler_(foo, i);
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/422b3750f986e32c)